# How to redirect a complete request URL with escaped query string?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL: http://example.org/abc?a=1&b=2 (the query string is variable).

I want to redirect it to the following URL using mod_rewite: http://example.org/test.php?url=abc%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2 (the query string is escaped).

I **don't** want the URL to become: http://example.org/test.php?url=abc&a=1&b=2,

which is what I get when I use: `RewriteRule ^(abc) test.php?url=$1 [QSA]`.

I also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ ([^\s]+)
RewriteRule ^(abc) test.php?url=%1
```

but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`B (escape backreferences)` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b) for this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(\S+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^abc/?$ test.php?url=%1 [L,NC,B]
```

Then check value of `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`, which will be shown as:

```
url=abc%3fa%3d1%26b%3d2
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this, similar to @anubhava:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(abc) test.php?url=$1\%3F%1 [B]
```

$1 is `abc`, %3F is `?`, %1 is the query string, all escaped using `B` flag.

Comment: There should not be any need to hardcode `%3F` in the rule and `THE_REQUEST` gives both URI and QUERY_STRING in same back-reference